# I want to print 19 random words and my password in a random order each time

Tags: python

This is my code so far. I have already made the 19 random words and I have made the password as I want. My problem is that I can't figure out one way to print those 19 words and my password together randomly every time.

```
import secrets
import string
import getpass
import random 

password = getpass.getpass()

honeywords_generator = (string.ascii_letters 
                        + string.hexdigits 
                        + string.digits 
                        + string.punctuation)

print('Your honeypot is ready:' , '\n')

for i in range(20):
    honeypot = ''.join(secrets.choice(honeywords_generator) for i in range(20))
    honeyword =''.join([ honeypot , password ,honeypot])
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. You want to put your password in the middle of other 19 words, ok. But you wanna print the words one by one or you wanna join them all together in a single string (because that's what `join` does) ?

Comment: I have made the 19 random worlds and the passwords as I want. For example, the password would be something like this  A)B;}*"9brQ8%jZ9ye\=LIKETHISRALUBRUSTOA)B;}*"9brQ8%jZ9ye\=                                                               
My problem is that I don't know how to print out those 19 worlds, and  my password

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of 20 words, then choose one word at random to replace with the password. Using these three lines in the place of your final 3 lines should fix the issue you are having.

```
words = [secrets.choice(honeywords_generator) for i in range(20)]
words[random.randint(0, len(words))] = password
print(''.join(words))
```

If you're satisfied with the honey"words" being only single characters, then this is a complete solution.

The difference between this code and the code you posted is that the code you posted places the password in the center of 2 different copies of the list of 20 random words, and the code I posted places the password at a random location in a list of 20 total words, without any copies.

Comment: I have already this, my problem is that I can't find out how to print the 19 random words, and only one time my new password

Comment: This code prints the password one time, and the 19 random words, dispersed on the left and right of it, randomly. How is what you want, different than what I have? Did you try using the code I posted? @GeorgePanagiotopoulos

Comment: Of course, I tried your code it's the same in my code if I print the honeyword.              
How can I print the password dipersed on the left and right of it randomly and other 19 random words without the passwords in the middle? That's my problem. Thank you Tyler

Comment: That is what this code does. This code picks 20 words, then chooses a random one to replace with the password. The password will not be placed in the middle every time. The code I sent is different from the code you wrote. The last 3 lines are changed, and they cause the password to be placed randomly among the other 19 words. I fail to see how that is not what you are looking for. Could you please describe the problem with more clarity?

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity on the solution. @GeoP

Comment: ooh, now I see the difference in your code from mine. when I run the previous it was very similar and I didn't figure it out. I have one more question if you can help me. How I can print this and the other 19 random words from honeywords_generator randomly? My target is to try and 'hide' the password first between random letters, symbols, etc. and then between the 19 random words every time in a different position

Comment: For example, I would like my output to be like this in a random way all the time  'DKAF0234*&$*!@#%$&^', 'MY_PASSWORD_HERE', 'BEKvOb8.zqe1{H3HK3DV'